# Fakepath while downloading the path to the file

Tags: javascript

I wrote myself such a mini script, because I need to download from the form the full path to the uploaded file. But there is a mistake - namely, I'm getting a path containing a fake path - why? Something I'm doing wrong? Something needs to be added here too?

```js
$("#showpath").on("click", function() {
 var showpath = document.getElementById("upload");
 alert(showpath.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="upload" id="upload" />
<button type="button" id="showpath">Show me path to file</button>
```

Comment: Nothing wrong here. Only your server can see the full name when you submit the form. See [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file)

Comment: Can not get out of this path in some other way? I intend to write a small script that selects a file from the disk, more accurately a photo and displays its preview.

Comment: There was a problem in my head, but before that I had to ask one question. Is there a way to change the path of the file being saved?

Comment: You can use [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) to show a preview of an image. There's even a working live example on the linked MDN article.